# Can't import uic from PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to load my .ui file in python and i want to use `uic.loadUI()` function but I have problem with importing it, I get an error:

```
*Cannot find reference 'uic' in '__init__.pyi'*
```

My code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("mybutton.ui", self)

app = QApplication([])
window = UI()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am using python 3.9.7. Installed PyQt5 with pip. Checked the PyQt5 folder and it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTlXs.png

Can You please help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular problem when using PyCharm.
The following Code fixed the issue:

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from os import path
```

```
FORM_CLASS, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "mybutton.ui"))
```

I Think its a Bug from PyCharm

Comment: Thank You very much, works fine

Answer (score 0):

Filip where do put the
FORM_CLASS, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(**file**), "mybutton.ui"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31286614)

Answer (score 0):

loadUi(path.join(path.dirname(**file**), "w.ui"),self)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).